# Recursively get nested URLs from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a Database table structured with nested URLs, using ParentID and ID to tell which piece of an URL belongs where.

Table structure looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+------------+-------------+
| ID  | ParentID |    Name    |      Url    |
+-----+----------+------------+-------------+
|   1 |        0 | Categories | categories  |
|  34 |        1 | Movies     | movies      |
| 281 |       34 | Star Wars  | star-wars   |
|  33 |        1 | Books      | a-good-book |
+-----+----------+------------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is that I want to be able to recursively go through all of the fields, and according to the ParentID, save all the possible url combinations.

So, from the table above, I'd like to get the following output:

```
mysite.com/categories
mysite.com/categories/movies
mysite.com/categories/movies/star-wars
mysite.com/categories/books
mysite.com/categories/books/a-good-book
```

I've started writing a CTE, looking like this:

```
  WITH CategoriesCTE AS
  (
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        Url, 
        ParentID, 
        ID 
    FROM myDB
    WHERE ParentID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        a.Name, 
        a.Url, 
        a.ParentID, 
        a.ID
    FROM myDB.a
    INNER JOIN CategoriesCTE s on a.ParentID = s.ID
  )

  SELECT * FROM CategoriesCTE
```

Thing is, this database call saves everything flat. What I would have to do, is that for EACH step, save all urls, and then for each ID, save the url according to what the ParentID is. Right now it of course isn't formatted but my output is flatly something like:

```
mysite.com/categories
mysite.com/movies
mysite.com/star-wars
mysite.com/a-good-book
```

Which creates a lot of broken links.
Is there some way to do an action/select for each recursive step? How should I be approaching this problem?

Comment: Is your data structure correct? The URL after categories has books, before it has a specific, but in the first table you describe, based on the relationship, it would go directly to categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what you think of this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SomeTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #SomeTable;

CREATE TABLE #SomeTable (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    ParentID INT NOT NULL,
    FolderName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UrlPath VARCHAR(8000) NULL 
    );
INSERT #SomeTable (ID, ParentID, FolderName) VALUES
    (1  , 0 , 'categories'),
    (34 , 1 , 'movies'),   
    (281, 34, 'star-wars'),  
    (33 , 1 , 'a-good-book');

-- SELECT * FROM #SomeTable st;

WITH 
    cte_Categories AS (
        SELECT 
            SitePath = CAST(CONCAT('mysite.com/', st.FolderName) AS VARCHAR(8000)),
            st.ID,
            NodeLevel = 1
        FROM 
            #SomeTable st
        WHERE 
            st.ParentID = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            SitePath = CAST(CONCAT(c.SitePath, '/', st.FolderName) AS VARCHAR(8000)),
            st.ID,
            nodeLevel = c.NodeLevel + 1
        FROM 
            cte_Categories c
            JOIN #SomeTable st
                ON c.ID = st.ParentID
        )
SELECT 
    c.SitePath,
    c.ID,
    c.NodeLevel
FROM 
    cte_Categories c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a few of new fields to your recursive CTE to track:

1. Depth of recursion (so you can find the record with the greatest depth
2. The path which will be built through each iteration by concatenating the latest value to it.
3. The starting point of the recursion so you know what record you started with

---

```
  WITH CategoriesCTE AS
  (
    SELECT Name, Url, ParentID, ID, 1 as depth, CAST(url as VARCHAR(500)) as path, url as startingpoint
    FROM myDB
    WHERE ParentID = 1
    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.Name, a.Url, a.ParentID, a.ID, s.depth + 1, a.url + s.path, s.url
    FROM myDB.a
    INNER JOIN CategoriesCTE s on a.ParentID = s.ID
  )

  SELECT * FROM CategoriesCTE
```